# AttributeError in module 'tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope'

Tags: python, tensorflow

setup:
windows 10,
gpu Nvidia 760,
python 3.5.2,
Anaconda 4.2.0,
Tensorflow 0.12,

when running either the Iris example or Deep & wide, I'm getting the same error related to fit_model in case of Iris:

```
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=2000)
```

produces the error

and for deep & wide

```
m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train, True), steps=200)
```

produces the same error

```
 File "C:\Users\OWNER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\python\ops\variables.py", line 203, in variable
    return variable_scope.get_variable(name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype,

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope' has no attribute 'get_variable'
```

I appropriate any help on this